# ''x'' is not a function

Tags: javascript

The function should return "This is True" however it doesn't appear to be working.  It is telling me

> `randomQuestion` is not defined.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//Questions
function randomQuestion() {
  var quest = "this is true";
  var string_length = 1;
  var randomstring = "";

  for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) 
  {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * quest.length);
    randomQuestion += quest.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
  }

  document.questions.questfield.value = randomQuestion;
}

<!--Questions form-->
<form name="questions">
<input type="button" value="question" onClick="randomQuestion();">&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="questfield" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: please add the code in text form to the question. please have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: You use `randomQuestion` instead of `randomstring` in your function.

Comment: why random? what should the function do?

Comment: in the future it should output a range of questions Nina Scholz.

Comment: Your `for` loop is never executed. The variable `string_length` is set to 1, and the for is `for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++){`, so unless you have `i<= string_length` or `string_length = 2`, the loop is never executed. That's the cause of your original error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your function is `randomQuestion`, but in your function, you write:

```
randomQuestion += ...
```

I noticed that you didn't use the variable `randomstring` in your function. Maybe you want to use `randomstring +=` instead of using `randomQuestion += ...`?

Here is the code I edited:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function randomQuestion() {
                var quest = "this is true";
                var string_length = 1;
                var randomstring = "";
                var i = 0;
                var rnum = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
                    rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * quest.length);
                    randomstring += quest.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
                }
                document.questions.questfield.value = randomstring;
            }
        </script>
        <form name="questions">
            <input type="button" value="question" onclick="randomQuestion();">
            <input type="text" name="questfield" value="">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would like to add that the reason that "randomQuestion" is not defined, may be that the original poster did not put script tags around his script.

Comment: He has put the tag around his script. Before he edited his post, there is a screenshot of his code(Now it is deleted)

Comment: Thank you for your help! This really helped me moving forward with my project.

Comment: btw. If you really wanted random questions :) I made a silly question generator version of your code :) https://jsfiddle.net/workingClassHacker/u2uvpt3e/4/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use an array with the quests and use the random index for access.

```js
function randomQuestion() {
  var quest = ["this is true", "this is not true", "this is more true", "this is less true", "this is never true"];
  document.questions.questfield.value = quest[Math.floor(Math.random() * quest.length)];
}
```

```html
<form name="questions">
  <input type="button" value="question" onClick="randomQuestion()">&nbsp;
  <input type="text" name="questfield" value="">
</form>
```